# /etc/dpkg/buildflags.conf example?

Tags: dpkg

[`dpkg-buildflags`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/man1/dpkg-buildflags.1.html) mentions /etc/dpkg/buildflags.conf file that can be used to configure `dpkg-buildpackage`. I cannot find any example of what the file should look like though. How could I for example make it pass `--disable-static` to `--configure`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As the man page explains, that file is used to set or modify compilation build flags, which are those passed to the preprocessors/compilers/linkers (cpp/gcc/ld for example, but other languages are also supported). An example content could be:

```
APPEND CFLAGS -ggdb -O3
STRIP CXXFLAGS -O2
```

I don't know of any --configure option, I guess you are talking about the configure script usually found on projects using autotools. But there's no global option to pass to that, because what build system each package uses is specific to that source package. If you need to pass that option you'll need to modify the debian/rules file.

Or propose to the debian-policy list, the addition of a new DEB_BUILD_OPTION tag to disable static libraries globally, which will need to be supported by every source package producing them.